# File is read-only while picking from android storage access framework

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to append a text to a file using the URI which i receive from an intent. When I pick the file directly from the storage, everything works perfectly fine. Nevertheless, the problem occurs when I pick the file from categorized selectors like Pictures, Videos, Musics and etc... It throws an IllegalArgumentException and says that the file is read-only.

```
private fun alterDocument(uri: Uri) {

    try {

        val subject = subjectField.editText!!.text.toString()
        val message = messageField.editText!!.text.toString()
        contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "wa")?.use { it ->
            // use{} lets the document provider know you're done by automatically closing the stream
            FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor).use {
                it.write("\n".toByteArray())
                it.write(
                    generateJSON(subject, message).toByteArray()
                )
            }
        }

    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

Does anyone knows any way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing in, yes I have necessary permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DocumentsProvider` does not have to grant read-write access to its content. In particular, `MediaDocumentsProvider` does not.

Unfortunately, [we do not have a way to limit the user to read-write content](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133539340). So, you are going to need to gracefully handle this error and suggest to the user that they pick from a different documents provider.

Or, to detect the problem more positively, you would need to check the document's flags to see if `FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE` is among them.

I [blogged](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/06/ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT-may-not-be-read-write.html) a bit more about this situation.

Comment: Thanks, currently i'm creating a file with the given URI and calling the canWrite() method on it before altering the file. Would that be enough? or I need to use FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE flag either.

Comment: @farzadchatrsimab: The problem with `canWrite()` is that it returns `true` if you can delete the content, but cannot open an `OutputStream` on it. IMHO, `canWrite()` really behaves more like `canWriteOrDelete()`. If you can live with that behavior, `DocumentFile` is fine.

Comment: Got it, can you just walk me through using FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE? How can I use it properly?

Comment: @farzadchatrsimab: The "simplest" thing to do is to grab the `canWrite()` implementation from [the file used for API Level 19 and higher](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.1-source/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentsContractApi19.java.html). You will need some other utility functions on that class (e.g., `getRawType()`, `queryForInt()`). Then, get rid of the `// Deletable documents considered writable` block, so your modified version does not pay attention to `FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE`.